# How to add a where condition based on context in a Postgraphile plugin?

Tags: postgraphile

I'm evaluating Postgraphile for a small experiment and was trying to add an implicit where condition to the generated SQL query for all the query operations based on the resolver context (for example, something like, `where(user_id = context.user_id)`.

I tried searching docs for a way to access `queryBuilder` in a resolver so I can do something like

```js
queryBuilder.where(sql.query`user_id = ${sql.value(context.user_id)}`);
```

but I did not find a way after searching for a lot of time. I'm sure there's a way - I just couldn't find it. Can anyone just point me in the right direction or just paste a link to the documentation? Thanks!

I already know that we can use RLS policy to add this condition but I have a complex where condition based on business logic that'd I'd like to write in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want your custom `WHERE` clause generated purely in javascript without utilizing RLS, the cleanest mechanism (using 4.12.9) would be creating a [graphile](https://www.graphile.org/graphile-build/plugins/) plugin that utilizes a field [hook](https://www.graphile.org/graphile-build/hooks/). Inside the context argument of your hook function, you will find [addArgDataGenerator](https://www.graphile.org/graphile-build/look-ahead/#when-processing-arguments-addargdatagenerator) which will allow you to append your `WHERE` clause to the relevant fields with `queryBuilder`. Additionally, `addArgDataGenerator` has the added benefit of allowing you to get the argument values and other resolve information for your field if you need to utilize that information as well.

```js
import type { Plugin } from "graphile-build";
import type { QueryBuilder, sql as sqlType } from "graphile-build-pg";
/**
 * Adds a custom where condition to fields meeting user defined criteria using a field hook
 */

const customWherePlugin: Plugin = (builder) => {
  builder.hook(
    "GraphQLObjectType:fields:field",
    (field, build, context) => {
      const { pgSql } = build;
      const sql = pgSql as typeof sqlType;
      const {
        scope: {
          isPgFieldConnection,
          isPgFieldSimpleCollection,
          pgFieldIntrospection: procOrTable,
          pgFieldIntrospectionTable: tableIfProc,
        },
        addArgDataGenerator,
      } = context;

      // use the scope to eliminate fields you aren't interested in adding custom logic to.
      // this particular example uses any connection type referencing the `posts` table.
      // The scope object gives you access to nearly all metadata from the schema and the database catalog itself,
      // so you can customize this to your heart's desire.
      const table = tableIfProc || procOrTable;
      if (
        (!isPgFieldConnection && !isPgFieldSimpleCollection) ||
        !table ||
        table.kind !== "class" ||
        table.namespaceName !== "my_schema" ||
        table.name !== "posts"
      ) {
        return field;
      }

      // this appends an additional where clause to the query builder when the field is specified in a gql query
      addArgDataGenerator(() => {
        return {
          pgQuery: (queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) => {
            const { userId } = queryBuilder.context;
            const tableAlias = queryBuilder.getTableAlias();
            queryBuilder.where(
              sql.fragment`${tableAlias}.user_id = ${sql.literal(userId)}`
            );
          },
        };
      });
      return field;
    },
    [],
    ["PgConnectionArgOrderBy"],
    []
  );
};

export default customWherePlugin;
```